# How can I clear memory in a Nativescript iOS application using videoplayer

Tags: ios, angular, video, nativescript

I'm building an Nativescript Application with the nstudio video player. We change the src of the video programmatically to offer different contents to the user.

I face a memory issue with the application as it is rising continuously in the user session.

Every time a new video is called, the memory rises and I can't find anyway to clear it.

I have tried with the destroy method but it doesn't change much. Is there any way to decrease the memory ?

Comment: you may need to try asking the NaviteScript CS about that firstly, and if there is no technical solution then report it as a bug.

Comment: I will try to do that on Discord... thks for reply